# What is the jBPM 7.1.0 restful API endpoint?

Tags: jbpm

The restful API (remotely do process management and task management etc) endpint in jBPM `6.5` is `localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/***`, but using `7.1.0`,  The same URL won't work. and from [jBMP 7.1.0 doc](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.1.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/), I couldn't find it.

Has the restful API endpiont changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jBPM 7 release kie-workbench(jbpm-console) didnt provide execution environment, it support only authoring of rules/BPMN files. Execution is supported only with kie-server.war file, because of this kie-workbench REST API's are removed from jBPM 7+.

Comment: so how do we access REST APIs? https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.7.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_wb.workbenchintegration

I see documentation, but no way to actually start the rest server